# Java : System.load and System.loadlibrary throws Unsatisfied link error in Windows XP, but not in Windows 7

Tags: file-upload

I am looking out for a solution/suggestions for the below problem with JNI:

I am trying to load a library file (*.lib) which is created on the fly from my code and placed in the temp folder of the file system. But when i try to load the same, with either `System.load` or `System.loadlibrary` in Java API, I am getting Unsatisfied link error.

Important thing here would be, I am running my application from command line using
`java -jar <executable-jar-file>`

I verified:

1. if the library file physically exists before loading
2. classpath & path variables are set properly
3. In my desktop I dont see any problems which has Windows 7.
4. I see this issue in test server with Windows XP but same java version.

Please suggest solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Windows NT? The most recent version is 4.0sp6a, but it was released over 11 years ago and hasn't been supported since maybe 2004.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is Windows XP Professional 2002 SP2. lot of probs on my head, so typo there !!!

Answer (score 0):

`loadLibrary` looks in the system path/library path. I don't think `TEMP` is included in this. Best way to do this is to build a full path based on the value of the `TEMP` environment variable and supply that path to `loadLibrary`:

```
String path = System.getenv( "TEMP" );
path += File.separator + "yourlibrary.dll"; //or in the case of linux will be yourlibrary.so!
System.loadLibrary( path );
```

Comment: Thanks Liv, but as I told the .lib file I use is dynamically generated with some secured name say libtmserialxxxxxxxxx.lib where xxxxx can be a random number. So I cant hard code as you said. And also though I set the path to temp properly from command line when I am running the jar file, I do get the Unsatisifed link error. Any help here....

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved.

Actually the problem is with the test server which does not have the required OS library bundles.

I downloaded the same from the below url :
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=766A6AF7-EC73-40FF-B072-9112BAB119C2&displaylang=en

and now its all set to go ....

thanks
balu